# How to auto increment id when copy the column into another table using PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

```
insert into usertable (employeenumber) select empno from usertemp
```

And this is the error

> ERROR:  null value in column "id" violates not-null constraint

Comment: Your `usertable.id` column doesn't have a `default`?

Comment: show us your create table? You need a sequence on `id`.

Comment: how to use sequence?

Answer (score 1):

Just create your table using `serial`, that will create the sequence and the default value

```
  CREATE TABLE usertable ( 
        id serial, 
        employeenumber integer
  );
```

Insert should be the same

```
insert into usertable (employeenumber) select empno from usertemp
```